# Putting uppercase letters taken from user and putting into an array

Tags: c, char, c-strings, uppercase, letter

In this code im trying to take a string from user and put the uppercase letters into a other array then print it. But im doing something horribly wrong i can tell, can someone help me with this code?

```
#include<string.h>

int main() {
   char arr[100],uppercaseletters[50];
   printf("Enter array:");
   scanf("%s",arr);
   strlen(arr);
   printf("The lenght of string is: %d\n",strlen(arr));
   for(int i=0;i<=strlen(arr);i++){
    if(arr[i]>='A' && arr[i]<='Z'){
        arr[i]+=uppercaseletters[50];
        printf("%s",uppercaseletters);
       }





   }

}
```

Comment: `arr[i]+=uppercaseletters[50];` What is this oddity ?

Comment: `i<=strlen(arr);` it should be `i<strlen(arr)`, otherwise you are looping one over the end of the string.

Comment: im trying to learn xD

Comment: @Pablo `i<=strlen(arr);` vs, `i<strlen(arr)` makes no functional difference here.  `'\0'` is not an uppercase letter.

Comment: Even assuming that your code were correct, think about this: what would happen if user enters a string with more than 50 uppercase characters?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica in this particular case no, but I see here a common pattern of shooting one past the end of the array in a for loop. Were the OP looping over an array of integers, this would be bad.

Comment: that 50 limit was temporary i was gonna change it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

It is unclear why the array `uppercaseletters` has less elements than the array `arr`.

```
char arr[100],uppercaseletters[50];
```

The user can enter a string consisting only from upper case characters.

This statement

```
strlen(arr);
```

does not have an effect.

This statement

```
arr[i]+=uppercaseletters[50];
```

does not make sense. You have to fill the array `uppercaseletters`. Moreover the element `uppercaseletters[50]` does not exist because the valid range of indices is `[0, 50)`.

In this statement

```
printf("%s",uppercaseletters);
```

you are trying to output a non-initialized array.

The program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )s[i] ) ) ++n;
    }

    char *upper_case_letters = malloc( n + 1 );

    n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )s[i] ) )
        {
            upper_case_letters[n++] = s[i];
        }
    }

    upper_case_letters[n] = '\0';

    puts( upper_case_letters );

    free( upper_case_letters );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look for example like

```
Enter a string: Hello World!
HW
```

Without dynamically allocating an array for upper case letters the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char s[N];
    char upper_case_letters[N];

    printf( "Enter a string: " );

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )s[i] ) )
        {
            upper_case_letters[n++] = s[i];
        }
    }

    upper_case_letters[n] = '\0';

    puts( upper_case_letters );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is a need for `malloc` here, you could have declared `char upper_case_letters[N]`. Other than that, nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> arr[i]+=uppercaseletters[50];

This is wrong. You want to add the uppercase letters to a new array, then use a separate index, such as j:

```
int j = 0;
int len = strlen(arr);
for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] >= 'A' && arr[i] <= 'Z')
    {
        // arr[i]+=uppercaseletters[50];
        if(j < 49)
        {
            uppercaseletters[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
}
uppercaseletters[j] = '\0';
printf("%s", uppercaseletters);
```

You also need to put the `printf` outside the loop as above - once the array has been populated.

Comment: ...and having the `strlen` inside the `for` is a massive performance hit...

Comment: @Pablo sounds like I'm going through a formal code review ;) thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

We will get a series from the user, we will throw the A-Z capital letters to another series and print it on the screen.

In fact, its logic is very simple. While navigating the items in the array with the 'for' loop, if A-Z detects letters, it assigns it to the new array.

1) Let's add our Standard Input / Output library and add our initial function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
```

2) Create the arrays and variables:

```
char arr[100], uppercaseletters[50];
int i=0, j=0;
//We created the variables 'i' and 'j' to navigate the characters of our series.
```

3) Let's get the array from the user:

```
printf("Enter array: ");
scanf("%s",&arr);
```

4) Let's create our loop, first return 'i = 0' and the number of items in the array.

The number of items in the array can be found with -strlen or -arr [i]! = '\ 0'.

```
for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++)
{
```

5) Let's add the condition to the loop.
If the 'i' element is greater than A and less than Z, add it to the other array.

```
if(arr[i]>='A'&& arr[i]<='Z')
{
    uppercaseletters[j++] = arr[i];
    //The reason we do 'j++' is to add to the 0th element of the array at first and it will be 'j = 1', then it will add to the 1st element and it will continue as 'j = 2'.
}
}
```

6) Let's print our upper case array on the screen.
Also, the number of items in our array was 'j'.

```
for(i=0;i<j;i++)
{
    printf("\n%c",uppercaseletters[i]);
}
//FİNİSH
return 0;
}
```

7) I hope this helps ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[100], uppercaseletters[50];
    int i=0, j=0;
    //We created the variables 'i' and 'j' to navigate the characters of our series.

    printf("Enter array: ");
    scanf("%s",&arr);

    for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]>='A'&& arr[i]<='Z')
        {
            uppercaseletters[j++] = arr[i];
            //The reason we do 'j++' is to add to the 0th element of the array at first and it will be 'j = 1', then it will add to the 1st element and it will continue as 'j = 2'.
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        printf("\n%c",uppercaseletters[i]);
    }
    //FİNİSH
    return 0;
}
```

My English is not so good :)